# how to gracefully kill all processes created by a python subprocess call to script which creates child processes (script, java, tee)

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sh

This gets a bit complicated. But in short i have a python script that calls a bash script which launches a long running java process via yet another bash script.  i've written another python process that will allow me to kill the process if need be.  The problem im having is that i see the processes for the two shell script disappear, but the java process and a 'tee' processes linger around and are labeled as 'defunct' ...hopefully i can make it more clear with some code..

**Python code to launch the bash/shell process**

```
#module level dict to store running processes that i may want to kill if they take too long
_processes={}

#call script - which will call another bash script, which will launch a java app, and tee some outputs to log and console
script = ''/apps/myapp/prep_and_launch''
process = subprocess.Popen([script, 'test1', "200"], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
_processes[script] = process
ret= process.wait()
```

**python code to kill the process**

```
process = _processes[script]
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)    
#process.terminate()
#process.kill()
```

**#script1 - which is called by the python code and calls a second script to launch a java app:**

```
#prep_and_launch.sh
#! /bin/bash
arg1=${1:-"test1"}
arg2=${2:-"100"}

#do some munging, setup, and prep for java run here

#call script to run java app
/apps/myapp/scripts/run_java_app.sh $arg1 $arg2
```

**script2 which launches the java and tees output**

```
#run_myapp.sh
arg1=$1
arg2=$2

LOG_DIR=/apps/myapp/logs/app.log
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx4G -Drs.logpath=$LOG_DIR"
EXEC_CMD="java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH com.myapp.TestApp $arg1 $arg2"

exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo "JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"| tee /dev/fd/3
echo "EXEC_CMD: $EXEC_CMD"| tee /dev/fd/3

exec $EXEC_CMD 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/3
```

So in the end, there are 4 processes i need killed gracefully - all four are indeed killed, but the java and tee processes still linger as "":

[image]

What am i missing here to cleanly kill the java and tee processes?

**EDIT: what is pid 1?**
definitely these are from the container build:
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253227/discussion-on-question-by-mike01010-how-to-gracefully-kill-all-processes-created); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.